# C# WPF textbox when binding data,how to add other strings in the Text property?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

```
<TextBox x:Name="V2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="{Binding airPlane}".../>
```

In the above code, if I want to add more things in the "Text" property besides binding the airplane data, e.g. to add a unit called "Pounds", how to modify the code? Thanks!

Comment: **In the above code** There is no code ;)

Comment: Are you sure, it is supposed to be a ``TextBox``? What is supposed to happen when someone enters ``Text`` into your ``Box``, what should ``airplane`` and ``pounds`` be? But, since you are talking about ``Units``, maybe this is enough for you: ``{Binding airplane, StringFormat={}{0}Pounds}``

Comment: you should use textblock not the textbox in WPF.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rand and Rohit! {Binding airplane, StringFormat={}{0}Pounds} This is very helpful for me. I should use textblock instead. Can I bind 2 data using only 1 textblock split by a slash?

Comment: You can use MultiBinding                                                                      <TextBlock>
          <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} \ {1} ">
              <Binding  Path="Value" />
              <Binding  Path="Value" />
            </MultiBinding>
          </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>

Comment: To let you know, if you want users to see a comment than you have to write the user as @RandRandom (for example) with this I will receive a notification and will check it. Without that, the chances are low for me to come back again, just pure coincidence that I now saw your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Converters` for it. For more see [**WPF Converters**](http://www.wpftutorial.net/valueconverters.html)

Comment: I was about to say this.. Anyway, this is the best option I see fit.

Comment: @Ephraim Seems like OP went with ``StringFormat``, wich in my opinion is the best option for his simple request. (see comments below question)